# Specify rows/columns of a fullscreen X terminal?

Tags: terminal, x11, xterm

For presentations it would be convenient to have a X terminal which supports following workflow:

- make it fullscreen
- specify how many columns/rows should be displayed

-> the terminal then automatically selects the right font type and size

Which X terminal supports this?

Comment: 1. Make it full screen: `xterm -fullscreen`. 2. Det how many columns should be displayed: enough to fill the screen. 3. Right font-type and size: subjective, so choose desired fontname and type `xterm -fullscreen -fs somefontype -fn somefontname`

Answer (score 0):

For determining the rows and columns, you could parse the output of `tput cols` and `tput lines` for your terminal size.  I'm not sure about a self-maximizing window though.

Comment: hm, with tput I get the geometry after the fact - thus I could use that information in some kind of (probably manual) iterative font size adjustment process.